# Implementing Pubnub notification in Android App

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, pubnub

I am developing chat app using Pubnub but I am having a problem with implementing push notification.
I have used following library for Pubnub

> **compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.10'**

and following for the FCM notification

> **> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'**

I am able to get push message if I send a message manually from Firebase console that indicates FCM has integrated properly.

I have enabled add-on as well for Push Notification in Pubnub account dashboard.

Then added FCM server as well over there.

Features like real-time messaging, History API callback and Presence API working pretty fine.

I have stuck in implementing push notification only.

When I searched for that I came to know about this method

```
pubnub.addPushNotificationsOnChannels()
    .pushType(PNPushType.GCM)
    .channels(Arrays.asList("ch1", "ch2", "ch3"))
    .deviceId("googleDevice")
    .async(new PNCallback<PNPushAddChannelResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(PNPushAddChannelResult result, PNStatus status) {
            // handle response.
        }
    });
```

but above method is no longer accessible for the SDK version that I've been using.

I know below method for the same but have no idea how it works.

```
 mPubNub.enablePushNotificationsOnChannel(channel, firebaseRegId, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void successCallback(String chanel, Object response) {
            super.successCallback(chanel, response);
            Log.e(TAG, "enablePushNotificationsOnChannel successCallback: " + chanel);
            Log.e(TAG, "enablePushNotificationsOnChannel successCallback: " + response);

            sendNotification();
        }

        @Override
        public void errorCallback(String s, PubnubError pubnubError) {
            super.errorCallback(s, pubnubError);
            Log.e(TAG, "enablePushNotificationsOnChannel errorCallback: " + s);
            Log.e(TAG, "enablePushNotificationsOnChannel errorCallback: " + pubnubError);

        }
    });
```

Any help or assistance in this matter will be greatly appreciated..!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right, just send the message in this format:

```
 public Map<String, Object> createmessage(String messageType, String messageId) {
        obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("messageType", messageType);
            obj.put("senderID", SharedPref.getInstance().getInt(SharedConstants.USER_ID) + "");
            obj.put("content", messagestring);
            obj.put("type", contentType);
            obj.put("userName", data.getName());
            obj.put("messageId", messageId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] encodeddata1 = Base64.encode(obj.toString().getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        String data = new String(encodeddata1);

        Map<String, Object> messagepayload = new HashMap<>();
        messagepayload.put("message", notification().toString());
        Map<String, Object> datapayload = new HashMap<>();
        datapayload.put("data", messagepayload);
        Map<String, Object> mobilePayload = new HashMap<>();

        mobilePayload.put("pn_gcm", datapayload);
        mobilePayload.put("pn_other", data);
        mobilePayload.put("pn_debug", true);
        Log.e("published message", mobilePayload.toString());
        return mobilePayload;
    }
```

And use this library:

```
compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub:4.0.9'
```

Hope this will help you out..let me know your feedback.

Comment: Thanks, @Deepak Rana, I knew about this library that you have mentioned.
But If I add this library instead, I will have to change a lot of things in my existing code.
So, It's not a preferable solution as I don't want to migrate right now.

Comment: Then you will have to use the API from the PubNub Android SDK in v3, not v4. The method you are trying to use is v4 API. https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/api-reference-mobile-push#adding-device-channel